# MySQL Trigger before update in same table

Tags: php, mysql, database, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger but I get the error:

> `#1442 - Can't update table 'materiaalverbruik' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger`

Now I know this is because you can't update in the same table but is there some kind of workaround? Below my trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `afterUpdateMateriaalverbruik` 
 BEFORE UPDATE ON  `materiaalverbruik` 
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    IF( NEW.kostenplaats_code <> OLD.kostenplaats_code ) THEN 
      UPDATE materiaalverbruik SET kostenplaats_code = NEW.kostenplaats_code
       WHERE artikelcode = OLD.artikelcode 
       AND materiaalverbruik_id != OLD.materiaalverbruik_id;
    END IF;
   END//
```

Edit: Someone marked this as duplicate but no solid answer was given in the duplicated question. I'm trying to update multiple records in the same table here. In the duplicated question, the answers given didn't provide an answer because it's about updating the same rows.